# I can't manipulate variant array

Tags: vba

I can't manipulate variant array.

```
Dim ArrayCellsVar(3) As Variant
For X=1 To 3
 For Y=1 To 3
  For K=0 To 2
    ArrayCellsVar(K) = Array(Cells(Y + K * 4, X).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False))
  Next K
 Next Y
Next X
MsgBox ArrayCellsVar(0)
```

I expect some cells (eg A1, A3, A5) in the array but I have the run-time error '9'

Comment: Do you expect to get the cells (Range datatype) or the address of the cells (String) ?

Comment: the address as A1 ( cell(1,1) ) or A3 ( cell(3,1) )
not the content

Comment: What is `lBound(ArrayCellsVar)` ?

Comment: You are overwriting the values in the destination array, you can skip the two first For loop and set X and Y to 3 statically, it would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

In my comment, I meant a reference to the Cell object, not only its content.
Here is an example to show you how to get the cells value, address or the cell object :

```vb
Dim ArrayCellsVarValue(3) As Variant
Dim ArrayCellsVarAddress(3) As String
Dim ArrayCellsVarCells(3) As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim k As Integer
For x = 1 To 3
    For y = 1 To 3
        For k = 0 To 2
            'Value
            ArrayCellsVarValue(k) = Cells(y + k * 4, x).Value
            'Address
            ArrayCellsVarAddress(k) = Cells(y + k * 4, x).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
            'The cell object itself
            Set ArrayCellsVarCells(k) = Cells(y + k * 4, x)
        Next k
    Next y
Next x
Debug.Print ArrayCellsVarValue(0)
Debug.Print ArrayCellsVarAddress(0)
Debug.Print ArrayCellsVarCells(0).Address & " contains [" & ArrayCellsVarCells(0).Value & "]"
```

Comment: And plz, rename your ```x```,```y``` and ```k``` variables to something easier to understand. Think about the maintenance of what you type